# Centos 6.9 error installing phpMyAdmin

Tags: centos, php, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to install phpMyAdmin and I get this error

> php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64

here goes some info

```
# rpm -qa php\* 
php-bcmath-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-php-gettext-1.0.12-1.el6.remi.noarch 
php-xml-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch 
php-cli-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-process-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-pecl-apcu-4.0.11-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 
php-gd-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-mbstring-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch 
php-pdo-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-tidy-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-mcrypt-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 
php-fedora-autoloader-1.0.0-1.el6.remi.noarch
```

and php version

```
# php -v
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2017 15:55:26) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Thanks for the help

---

EDIT

Tried to update to PHP 5.6 `# yum install php55w-pdo-5.5.38-1.w6.x86_64` and get lot of error, so tried to remove PHP with `yum remove php`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: php
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.xfree.com.ar
 * epel: mirror.uta.edu.ec
 * extras: centos.xfree.com.ar
 * remi: remi.xpg.com.br
 * remi-safe: remi.xpg.com.br
 * updates: centos.xfree.com.ar
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Package(s) php available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

here it said `not installed` but it's installed

```
# php -v
PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2017 08:33:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install a package for PHP 7, whilst having PHP 5 installed.  Either install the relevant PHP 5 package, or upgrade your PHP installation to PHP 7 to resolve the conflict.

Comment: I don't want php7, so how can I make to install phpMyAdmin for php5?

Comment: Ensure that phpMyAdmin is still compatible with PHP5, and if so, follow the installation instructions for installing on that version of PHP.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you specify the steps?

Comment: updated with new steps

Comment: Could be a conflict or issue with packages from the `remi` and `remi-safe` repositories. I have a CentOS 6.9 Vbox image with MySQL, PostgreSQL, PHP5, and both phpMyAdmin and phpPgAdmin. All packages came from either base, epel, or extras repositories.